# unable to retrieve metadata for unrecognized element providers

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, database-connection, connection-string

I get a message error whenever I try to add a controller with Entity framework template but I keep getting a error message

```
    unable to retrieve metadata for 'path' unrecognized element providers. 
         (C:\Users\user\appdata\local\Temp-mp6124.tmp line 78)
```

I know it's something related to connection string so here is my connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NoktatyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=NoktatyContext-20140122154208; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|NoktatyContext-20140122154208.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What does the `<entityFramework>` section of your web.config or app.config look like?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by removing the `<providers>` section of the configuration file.

This:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Becomes this:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

I had this issue this morning and just found the fix.   If you don't specify the database (and provider I guess) EF will default to SQL Server Express.

Comment: Awesome man! I just wanted to add, for the people that are following the ASP.NET MVC tutorial on w3schools, this was the solution for me.

Comment: The reason for this is if you start a project targeting .NET 4.5 and then use a version of EntityFramework in a referenced assembly which isn't expecting that element. I.e. a version of EF prior to v5 (or EFv5 itself for .Net 4.0, which is actually EFv4.4)

Comment: In my case I had duplicate providers and multiple entityFramework tags in my app.config. I combined them under one entityFramework tag and this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later

Please unistall current version Entity Framework, vs Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0.

Delete tag ...

Restart VS

OK

Comment: this is no longer true